# airflow pod failing with crashloopbackoff error

Tags: kubernetes, installation, airflow

I'm new to Kubernetes and wanted to install airflow application.
I have been trying to install airflow on Kubernetes.
I'm following the blog https://www.confessionsofadataguy.com/deploying-apache-airflow-inside-kubernetes/ and github https://github.com/danielbeach/airflow-kubernetes/tree/master

[All resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Pln.png)

[describe airflow pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukc4n.png)

[logs of the airflow pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dappa.png)

[airflow service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o1nB.png)

Inside the postgres pod I've installed airflow with below command:

[airflow-command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCGmo.png)

And to initialize the db I've ran  inside the postgres pod.

`airflow db init`

Any idea on how to fix this issue or how I can debug it?

Comment: Couple of issues that I see - 1. "could not translate host name" usually comes when there is some issue in the K8s DNS Server (`CoreDNS`) 2. Your service `airflow` has no `Endpoints` attached to it means it won't be able to direct any traffic to a pod. 3. Lastly it would be better to follow the [official documentation for Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/kubernetes.html) instead of following some outdated blogs. You can get everything setup by using a [Helm Chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html)

Comment: Hi Krishna welcome to SO. Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks for your suggestion, as I'm new asking questions on SO, will follow guidelines from next time

Comment: @Sibtain thanks for your suggestion, I will follow the official documentation for Airflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.